# Issue with production release of CUDA Toolkit 4.0 and Nsight 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, nvidia, directory, project-settings

I previously had the release candidates of both programs, then I uninstalled them and installed the production releases of the programs. This includes the CUDA toolkit, Parallel Nsight, and the GPU computing SDK. When I go to Project->Build Customizations and select CUDA 4.0, I am no longer able to set the .cu file as a CUDA C/C++ file, and when I try reloading the project, I get an error that reads:

`The result "" of evaluating the value "$(CudaBuildTasksPath)" of the "AssemblyFile" attribute in element <UsingTask> is not valid.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 4.0.targets`

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The handling of the extension/build task properties seems to have changed. (It has for me coming from cuda 3.2, nsight 1.5, vs 2010)

I was able to resolve the issue by fixing/changing the vcxproj file:

look for

```
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings" />
```

or

```
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
```

replace with

```
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 4.0.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
```

Just a quick **update**: NVIDIA provides a fix at [their developer pages](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-40).
Look for *CUDA Toolkit 4.0 Build Customization BUG FIX Update*

Comment: Did you make the change in the .vcxproj file that is created by the Conversion Wizard when attempting to open a VS 2008 / CUDA 3.2 project in VS 2010 / CUDA 4.0? That did not work for me because the Conversion Wizard fails before it has added any of the source files to the .vcxproj file.

Comment: I tried that, the xml text you described is already there. I've made a post on the NVIDIA forums here: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=201433 There's an example project that won't work attached to my posting, and it also has the text you described.

Comment: @seljuq70 : I downloaded your sample. It looks like in your project file visual studio did something different and you need to replace `  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>` with `  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 4.0.props" />
  </ImportGroup>` ... It loaded properly for me after doing that.

Comment: @Roger Dahl I edited to reflect that I was coming from cuda 3.2, nsight 1.5, vs 2010. I don't have cuda 3.2/vs 2008 setup anymore.

Comment: It works, but how do I stop Visual Studio from doing this with every project, what needs to be changed?

Comment: @Simon Hey NVIDIA acknowledged there was a bug and posted the fix. Everything is back to normal. I appreciate the help.

Comment: perfect, I just added the link to my original answer for reference.